# Checking row exists _app_ctx Flask SQLite

Tags: python, api, sqlite, rest, flask

I have the following `get_db()` function that I use to get my SQLite database:

```
def get_db():
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if not hasattr(top, 'sqlite_db'):
        top.sqlite_db = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    return top.sqlite_db
```

I believe i ma not using Python SQLite cursor here. If I do the following:

```
db = get_db()
db.execute('DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=3')
db.commit()
```

How would I check if the ID passed in DELETE exists? I tried using rowcount in sqlite3.Cursor but that does not work with the way I am retrieving my database here.

How would I check for that? I need it to return 404 if the the ID passed does not exist.

Thanks

Comment: Then why don't you use a cursor?

Comment: Wouldn't this whole get_db function be redundant then?

Comment: You'd still need the database object to get the cursor from.

Comment: I tried that. Rowcount always returns -1 and fetchone returns None so that obviously is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you query the ID first and throw 404 if does not exist. Something like:

```
cur = g.db.query('select * from table_name where id=3')
if cur.rowcount <= 0:
*    abort(404)
''Run delete command here''
```

Comment: Yep just found out fetchone, fetchall and rowcount only work after SELECT.